# Conflict in using ui-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Recently, I have an error regarding to my pagination that can't be updated after filter. Luckily, this was managed, however, now I'm dealing with a conflict regarding to the usage of ui-bootstrap. As I have my project, Im using,

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

Based on the codes that I'm relaying with they used,

```
<script src="angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.2.0.js"; type="text/javascript"></script>
```

***Here's the thing, I do have as well a datepicker in my codes. But when I used the

```
<script src="angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.2.0.js"; type="text/javascript"></script>
```

this datepicker doesn't work. If now I will switch to my formerly ui-bootstrap

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

, now the pagination after filter can't be used but the datepicker will work. Any ideas how to solve this or what I'm going to do? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, your problem is due to directive conflict; e.g. you have a custom directive defined called "datepicker":

`angular.module('App').directive('datepicker', ...`

That's going to cause problems because UI-Bootstrap also defines a directive with the same name. The simplest solution would be to simply exclude the `datepicker` module from UI-Bootstrap.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

On their website, you can choose "create a build". It will allow you to download a version of UI-Bootstrap custom-tailored to your needs by adding and removing certain modules, like the datepicker.

Then you will drop the file into your HTML:

`<script src="path/to/your/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

I notice you are using Bower to manage your dependencies. Unfortunately, Bower can't work with a custom UI-Bootstrap build; you'll have to manage the file yourself (put it in a subdirectory, like "assets/").

Comment: May I ask for the clarification on the thing that you want me to do? I'm not so familiar with it and I am also a beginner in using angularjs. Please provide a step by step if do so, Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer. If that's not what your problem is, let me know and I'll add a clarification request comment telling you what I need to understand your problem.

Comment: sorry for the confusion this may have caused. Already did some coding in my codes and finally fixed the problem. Thanks anyway for the help!!